# Maven + Surefire: Overwrite temp and output directory

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to overwrite temporary and output directory for surefire plugin. I have following plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <tempDir>c:/tmp/a-tests-temp</tempDir>
        <outputDirectory>c:/tmp/a-tests-out</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It does not work. It continue using `/target/surefire` and `target/surefire-reports`.

The idea is to split different concurrency maven test runs over the same project directory for quick tests on the developer workstation.

Comment: Based on the documentation I would only set [reportsDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply, ive only managed to use relative path location to change the path for the temp folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <testClassesDirectory>${project.buildDirectory}/test-classes</testClassesDirectory>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.buildDirectory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <classesDirectory>${project.buildDirectory}/test-classes</classesDirectory>
        <tempDir>../${project.buildDirectory}/surefire</tempDir>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
        </includes>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <geb.env>${geb.env}</geb.env>
            <geb.build.reportsDir>${project.buildDirectory}/${geb.build.reportsDir}</geb.build.reportsDir>
            <com.athaydes.spockframework.report.outputDir>${project.buildDirectory}/spock-reports</com.athaydes.spockframework.report.outputDir>
            <com.athaydes.spockframework.report.aggregatedJsonReportDir>${project.buildDirectory}/spock-reports</com.athaydes.spockframework.report.aggregatedJsonReportDir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```